# Office for Mac buy from Sweden

Tags: mac, ms-office

I am interested in buying Office for Mac 2011. I am in Sweden. Whenever I want to buy it from a website it shows like **Office för Mac Hem och Student 2011 - 1 Paket (Svenska)**. Does it means software language is Swedish? I want it in English, as I am not Swedish. And my MacBook Pro (OS X Lion) language is English. Should I buy this one?

Comment: Office for mac isn't at all like the windows counterpart (it's kinda sketchy tbh)… i know this is kind of off topic, but i HIGHLY suggest you try office for mac and iWork and see which you like more first

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX What do you mean "sketchy"? I have Office: Mac 2011 on several Macs and I usually prefer it to the Windows version.

Comment: the ui is inconsistent and often total different from what people expect after using windows' version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem. What matters is the **serial**.

The *same serial should work with any language version* of Office Mac 2011 which you can download from Microsoft's official websites.

I had a similar problem like you. I had purchased an English version via Ebay,  but I needed a German one. I downloaded the German version and used it with and US version serial without any problems.

In your case you can download the US version here: [www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried buying the US English version directly from Microsoft's website ([link](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/list/categoryID.50726500?WT.term=office+mac+2011&WT.mc_id=pointitsem_Microsoft+US_google_5+-+OMac+2011&WT.medium=cpc&WT.campaign=5+-+OMac+2011&WT.content=7bMBVEXy&WT.srch=1&WT.source=google&cshift_ck=57B02969-6DAC-44EA-A187-239AC33C54EEcs7bMBVEXy))? It's a download (no disc).